# How to get data from Contract State form of a state, without casting?

Tags: java, kotlin, state, corda

Is there a way to retrieve data from ContractState form of a state data, without casting ? I was trying like this given below using reflections, but it doesnt gave values (I guess it is returning state field "status" 's metadata).

```
historyForId is of type : ArrayList<Map<String,ContractState>>
val temp2 = historyForId.first().get("contractStateData")!!.javaClass.getDeclaredField("status")
```

Comment: please share ContractState class

Comment: @ShaluTD its corda ContractState type. Not a user defined one.

Comment: Could you add more code snippets? How did you get the ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the answer as found on Corda ledger slack. It was found that "isAccessible" for the field was set to false. The issue was resolved by assigning "isAccessible" to true explicitly.

Comment: Hi @Ashutosh.Thanks for the response. Hope you realise that I am the same Benjamin, which we had discussion over this in slack.

Comment: Hey yes, Benjamin. I guessed so since the questions were very identical.